# PHP Photo Upload Problems (Mobile)

Tags: php, android, file-upload

I have an HTML form which allows users to submit a photo from their phone, and it places the pictures into an AWS S3 bucket. First, it places the photo into the upload directory, and then uploads it from there. The problem I am running into is uploading to the upload directory. It works fine on an iphone, but on a Galaxy Note 3, it will only allow uploads if you take the picture then. And on a Galaxy S5 it will not work at all (Though last time I tried with the Galaxy using a fresh picture, it wouldn't even submit the form, and the guy who owns it isn't here right now).

The file upload form:

```
<form action="photo.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<p>Name: <input type="text" name="person" /></p>
<p>DOB: <input type="text"  name="dob" /></p>
<p>File: <input type="file" name="thePhoto" accept="image/*" /></p>


<input name="submit" type="submit" />
</form>
```

For the Photo Upload:

```
$allowed_filetypes = array('.jpg','.jpeg','.png','.gif');
$max_filesize = 10485760;
$upload_path = 'upload/';

$filename = $_FILES['thePhoto']['name'];
$ext = substr($filename, strpos($filename,'.'), strlen($filename)-1);

if(!in_array($ext,$allowed_filetypes))
    die('The file you attempted to upload is not allowed.');

if(filesize($_FILES['thePhoto']['tmp_name']) > $max_filesize)
    die('The file you attempted to upload is too large.');

if(!is_writable($upload_path))
    die($upload_path);
```

This second bit of code is what comes into play if the file failed to upload, but it wasn't for the reasons in the first bit of code.

```
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['thePhoto']['tmp_name'],$upload_path . $filename)) {
    Echo 'It worked!';
} else {
    echo 'There was an error during the file upload.  Please try again.';
}
```

I'm getting the error echo from the second bit of code when uploading from existing pictures on a Galaxy Note 3. Any Ideas on what could be the problem?

Comment: What error do you get? How does it fail? Can we see the full HTML for the file upload form?

Comment: I don't get an actual "Error". It just fails to upload the photo, and then gives me the error echo from the second bit of code. I'll update my post to include the full form.

Comment: To debug it further try adding print_r($_FILES); after the error echo. That should tell you if/what errors happened during upload.